# How to make a Bulma tooltip visible if it overflows on x a parent container that has a scroll on y

Tags: html, scroll, tooltip, overflow, bulma

In the snippet below, the tooltip of a document is partially cropped (you may need to resize the window to see it), as if I had **overflow-x: hidden**, and although I have **overflow-x: visible** it creates a scroll on x.

I want the tooltip to be fully visible without the need to scroll on x, while style being able to scroll on y.

**Notes** :

1 - there are similar questions but no true answer.

2 - You can see [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Flyout/sncj1umq/25/) instead of the snippet.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-tooltip@3.0.2/dist/css/bulma-tooltip.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="columns" style="height: 370px">

  <div class="column is-one-third">
    <nav class="panel position-relative w-100 h-100">
    
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <p>Documents</p>
      </div>
      
       <div class="panel-block is-block" style="height: 140px; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: scroll">
         <a class="panel-block is-block">
           <span data-tooltip="This is the document number 1" class="has-tooltip-right">Document 1</span>
         </a>
         <a class="panel-block is-block">
           <span data-tooltip="This is the document number 2" class="has-tooltip-right">Document 2</span>
         </a>
         <a class="panel-block is-block">
           <span data-tooltip="This is the document number 3" class="has-tooltip-right">Document 3</span>
         </a>
         <a class="panel-block is-block">
           <span data-tooltip="This is the document number 4" class="has-tooltip-right">Document 4</span>
         </a>
         <a class="panel-block is-block">
           <span data-tooltip="This is the document number 5" class="has-tooltip-right">Document 5</span>
         </a>
       </div>
       
       <div class="panel-block is-block position-absolute fixed-bottom border-top">
         <input type="file">
       </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column is-two-thirds h-100">
    PDF viewer
  </div>
</div>
```